# When data are zeros show on y axis only zeros. (ECharts)

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

Hello everyone here is my axisLabel formatter

```js
      yAxis: {
        show: true,
        type: "value",
        min: 0,
        // max: function (value) {
        //   return Math.ceil(value.max);
        // },
        axisLabel: {
          formatter: (val) => {
            console.log(val);
            return props.time
              ? timeFormatter(val / 1000)
              : Math.ceil(val) + ` ${props.units}`;
          },
        },
```

This is what I get for my y-axis all 1ones because of Math.ceil
[image]

If I don't use my formatter I get this

[image]

What I want is if all my data is zero to show zeros on my y-axis

Comment: Its not clear to me what your expected result should look like. Can you provide an example image or implementation in the [echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html)?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sdjykz
As you can see the y-axis goes 0,0.2,0.4 etc. When all data is zero

Comment: I want instead of 0,0.2,0.4 etc to be 0,0,0,0,0

Comment: can you not just Format with `math.floor` instead of `math.ceil`?

Comment: Math.floor output is 0,0,0,0,1. In this case if its possible to remove the 3 zeros between the first one and the one would be okay

Comment: Take a look at [`yAxis.max`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.max) as a function and [`yAxis.minInterval`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.minInterval). This should do the trick.

Comment: I tried max, I will look into minInterval probably, will need a flag to check whenever I should show 1 or more intervals.

Comment: `minInterval` specifies the smallest tick size. So if you set it to 1 the axis should only show the 0 and 1 tick. If you set `yAxis.max` to a value <1 it should only show 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness I'll write a full answer here:

You can specify the smallest interval between two ticks with [`minInterval`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.minInterval). If you set `minInterval` to 1 your axis should only show 0 and 1.

If you want it to show only 0 you can set [`showMaxLabel`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.showMaxLabel) to `false`.

The default [`max`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.max) value seems to be 1. You could also specify a different max value depending on your current maximum data value via `max: (value) => value.max + <some_value>`.

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeBYAULWAPAgliAzgFzLqaZgCeIApiQOQDGAhmDQObABOl9ANGXIATVsxIBtegFkY_WPQAqAVxpz6AdRpC1CgBZK1AMS4Q1AZVbml0egF1BAXwEZYlPIRKoXFanXkA3ZgAbFX5BTABbCGgASWg2LkCgkgBGZ3JYZnwCABlmACMaZOQCXWAAdyksvMLigDNgghoHR3TYJpMaYlhxcNJvYVEJAAY-WFHxsYnpqds2jKpaBiDo1T6Wl3s0ByA) is an example showing only 0 on the yAxis:

```js
import * as echarts from 'echarts';

var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
var option;

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    minInterval: 1,
    axisLabel: { showMaxLabel: false }
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I didnt use this method instead we did something like this
`title: {
        show: props.data.length === 0,
        textStyle: {
          color: "#F7F3F0",
          fontSize: 20,
        },
        text: "No data available",
        left: "center",
        top: "center",
      },`

Not sure why the formatting doesn't work.